# Formula to count if a text is written in a cell

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| a | 0 |
| a | 1 |
|  |  |
| a | 2 |
| a | 3 |
|  |  |
| a | 4 |

[image]

Count starts at 0.
ArrayFormula is used and data is checked in a specified range.
If a value is written in the cell, it counts. However, if the cell is empty, it does not count.
I want to express it in a formula!

Comment: Have you tried LEN() ?

Comment: Side note: Microsoft Excel is not synonymous with Google Sheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SCAN, like this:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A1:A10="",,SCAN(-1,A1:A10,LAMBDA(a,c,a+(c<>"")))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this formula in P1. If you start in O2, change O:O with O2:O

```
=BYROW(O:O,LAMBDA(each,IF(each="","",COUNTA(FILTER(O1:each,ISTEXT(O1:each))))))
```

Comment: PS: in this case, this counts text values only, though it was what you meant. Leave it here if it's useful for anyone else